# customized login block

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I made a template for the login block on the main page. It works.

Here is user-login.tpl.php code:

```
<?php
    $elements = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
?>
<div class="login">
    <div class="login_header">Login</div>
<?php
print drupal_render($elements["form_id"]);
print drupal_render($elements['name']);
print drupal_render($elements['pass']);
?>
      <div class="forgot_password">
             <a href="/" class="forgot_password">Forgot password</a>
      </div>
       <input type="submit" name="" value="Log in" />
       <a href="/" id="sign_up">Sign up</a>
</div>
```

`<form>` and `<div>` tags were added around my template code, breaking the layout. Now the block doesn't float: left.

Here is the rendedered HTML:

```
<form action="/node?destination=node" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="login">
    <div class="login_header">Login</div>
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login_block" />
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
  <label for="edit-name--2">Login <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-name--2" name="name" value="" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
  <label for="edit-pass--2">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="password" id="edit-pass--2" name="pass" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
</div>
      <div class="forgot_password">
             <a href="/" class="forgot_password">Forgot password</a>
      </div>
       <input type="submit" name="" value="Log in" />
       <a href="/" id="sign_up">Sign up</a>
</div>
</div></form>
```

How to remove extra `<div>` and put the form inside `<div class="login">`? I tried that manually, but then I get 2 forms.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the rendered html for that image in your question?

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alter the form on the theme layer to wrap the form in a div...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function YOURTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    //dsm($form_id);

    if ($form_id == 'YOURFORMID') {
        // add prefix and suffix to form
        $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="form-class">';
        $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }
}
```